# Singleton Class Property

Tags: c#, singleton

I am using Singleton and I have this code:

```
string check = textbox1.Text;
```

The textbox is in another page, which is Page 1.

I've got an error message which shows that

> "textbox1 doesn't exist in current context"

in the Singleton page.

Tried Google and failed. Help needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: textbox1 would be available in Form Class, are you trying to access it in some other class?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Singleton page'? Do you mean the master page?

Comment: How does your so called singleton page access other controls in the same page along with the textbox1?

Comment: Show us enough of your Singleton class to give context to that line of code, and enough of your "other page" to show where `textbox1` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

The modifier of text box is private so you cannot access it from another page.